Express и MySQL создание соединения с базой данных с данными User-а
Мы создаем соединение к базе, используя стандартную конструкцию
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'user',
  password : '1111',
  database : 'test'
});

Каким образом можно задавать эти данные при подключении пользователя, который внесен в базу со своими привилегиями, со своим именем и паролем, как бы меняя этот объект динамически.
Может можно создать подключение к Mysql в каком-то Middleware, получив из frontend-а имя и пароль  user-а. Спасибо.

Гм... а зачем? Что вы хотите с этого получить? что именно будет "меняться динамически"?

К базе данных подключены пользователи со своими Privileges (что им можно в базе делать, что нельзя и т.д.). Я хочу что бы такой пользователь подключался к базе со своим ником и паролем и сответственно со своими привилегиями. К тому же я не хочу чтобы пароль к базе данных размещался в файле index.js или .env, чтоы его вносил пользователь при подключении. Если, наример, сервер расположен локально на компе, его можно просто прочитать

т.е. сценарий приблизительно такой: при авторизации в приложении юзер по этому же паролю подключается к базе данных Mysql, создает индивидуальное подключение.

Не, а в чём проблема-то? Есть приложение. Для запуска используются логин и пароль. Для каждого экземпляра приложения генерится в приложении рандомное имя, а на сервере создаётся отдельная учётная запись с этим именем. В отличие от экземпляров приложений, где всё может и совпасть, учётная запись случайна и в пределах MySQL уникальна. Пароль - тот же, что и у учётки приложения, или отдельный. Забота админа - установить соответствие экземпляра приложения и созданной учётной записи со случайным именем, и раздать этой записи требуемые свойства (привилегии, участие в группах, дефолтная БД и прочее).

... то есть если юзер использует приложение на двух компах, у него две учётные записи с разными именами, но совпадающим на бором привилегий. И, возможно, с совпадающим паролем. я не хочу чтобы пароль к базе данных размещался в файле index.js или .env Само собой пароль не размещается вообще нигде. Пользователь вводит его ручками при старте приложения.

Вы все правильно пишите, но как это реализовать на практике на Expess я не видел,  вот только такой способ, как выше везде описывается, т.е заранее подключаемся к базе на этапе запуска сервера и тд. Если в БД я что-то понимаю, то Node.js я не очень силен. В любом случае, спасибо за участие.

Подумаешь... я тоже в JScript ни ухом ни мордой - и что? коню понятно, что если код настройки соединения соответствует показанному коду, то ничто не помешает там вместо литералов использовать переменные, значения которых получены в предыдущем соединении.
